# Magnetic field due to circular surface current density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I am trying to find the magnetic field between two coaxial cylindrical shells of radius $a$ and $b$ respectively. They have a surface current density of $K = K_0cos(\theta)\hat{\theta}$ and $K=-K_0cos(\theta)\hat{\theta}$ respectively. My thought process so far is to use an amperian loop,
\begin{equation}
B2\pi r = \mu_0 I_{enc}
\end{equation}
However, I am having problems with the $I_{enc}$ part. Since
\begin{equation}
I_{enc} = \int K \cdot dl_{\perp}
\end{equation}
The length perpendicular to the current flow would be $l$. But then we would have,
\begin{equation}
B = \frac{\mu_0 K_0 cos(\theta)}{2\pi r} \hat{z}
\end{equation}

But it feels wrong to have the $cos\theta$ in the magnetic field formula. Moreover, I then have to calculate the angular momentum per unit length which would mean I would have to integrate over the $cos\theta$ and that would equal $0$.

Comment: How have you gone from $\int \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl}$ to $|\vec{B}|2\pi r$? The current has a $\hat\theta$ component meaning the magnetic field does  not follow your amperian loop? You're confusing the procedure for solving for a current with a purely $\hat z$ component where the B field is parcelled to dl

Comment: Current enclosed, is, and should be zero.  the current density is perpendicular to your amperian loop and thus the flux integral is 0